# Ajax and Mongodb, use _id

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a test project using express.js that displays all items in a mongo database on a webpage. Each database entry is displayed on the page with a button to delete it.

```
-each i in docs
        p ----------------------
        p <strong>Name: #{i.name}
        p <strong>Type: #{i.type}
        p <strong>Amount: #{i.quantity}
        p <strong>ID: #{i._id}    
        input(type = 'button', value ="delete item", id='delete')
```

I want the button to send a DELETE request to `/api/item/_id`

My script is as follows

```
script(type='text/javascript').
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#delete").click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    url: '/api/item/' + this._id
                }).done(function(result) {

                });
            });
        });
```

This is not sending the desired request. How would I go about passing the _id from the item to the button?

If I set the URL to a know _id, like below, it works and the item is deleted

```
url: '/api/item/56f3e800d6f24d0819e43fcc'
```

Thanks in advace

Comment: How about data- attribute for the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [data-](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute

Html

```
<input type="button" id="delete" data-id="mongo id here" />
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'DELETE',
   url: '/api/item/' + this.attr('data-id')
 })
```

Also you'd better use class instead of id="delete"

Comment: Thanks for this! Solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your looping code you appear to be assigning the same HTML ID attribute to each button:

```
input(type = 'button', value ="delete item", id='delete')
```

That makes for **invalid** HTML (only one item can have a given ID).  You can make the `delete` attribute a **class** where its legal to have more than one item with the same class.

If you `console.log(this)` when any of these buttons are clicked what is `this` referring to?  What `_id` do you get?  Do you get the same `_id` regardless of what button is clicked?